# WP7 - access private variables

Tags: windows-phone-7, reflection, private-members

Imagine this:

```
Class A{
private int a;
}

Class B{
  public void fn(){
    A obj=new A();
    // access obj's private variable a here.
  }
}
```

I want to access obj's private variable a, as commented out. Reflection doesn't work as it throws a fieldaccessexception. I want to access a. Is there any other way to do it? I cannot change access modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only access public, internal or protected members (that is, fields, methods, etc.) on Windows Phone.

Reflection on Windows Phone does not allow access to private members. I would recommend you use "internal" for internal members you wish to access.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that on Windows Phone. You can't access the `a` field from outside the class. If you have the source code of the `A` class, you may want to change the visibility of the field. Otherwise, you're stuck.